# The theme disappears when I add a matcher in the select2 code

Tags: jquery-select2, select2-rails

When I add the matcher in the select2, the bootstrap theme is gone. However, when I delete the matcher, the bootstrap theme reappears in the website. Is there a way to add the bootstrap theme and the matcher together?

```
$('.gas_a').select2({
  matcher: matchStart(params, data),
  theme: "bootstrap"
});
```